# Installing IPOPT in Linux (to be used with Pyomo)

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo, ipopt

I am trying to install ipopt in a Linux machine but without success...

I have followed the steps in https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/INSTALL.html.

I am able to sucesfully compile it but in the end it seems that the bin folder is not beeing created, instead I have a lib, share and include folders

My goal is to use IPOPT with pyomo and since I do not have the bin folder, I cannot set the PATH enviroment variable neither the executable parameter...

[image]

I wonder if someone could give me light on that, thanks

Comment: Have you tried `make test` and `make install` after the build?

Comment: Yes, I tried the steps in https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/INSTALL.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, the problem was with the permission of the file.

After using "chmod u+x ipopt" in the bin folder, worked.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to install the AMPL Solver Library (https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/INSTALL.html#EXTERNALCODE_ASL) before building Ipopt. Pyomo may call Ipopt through its AMPL interface. The Ipopt executable is only build if ASL was found during configure.